# having issues with pykd (pykd.DbgException: Call IDebugClient::GetOutputCallbacks failed HRESULT 0x80010107)

Tags: python, windbg, pykd

I'm working with pykd and am able to connect it with my debugger (windbg) but for some reason I'm unable to process any command with `pykd.dbgCommand` not sure what the issue is as I've tried multiple methods to try and resolve the issue:

- Reinstall pydk + python
- tried on python2.7, python3.5, python3.8
- tried a different system + different debug session

when I tried to run the command on the windbg session it was able to produce the results but somehow it's now able to do that from python console.

```
pykd.dbgCommand("!analyze -v")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pykd.DbgException: Call IDebugClient::GetOutputCallbacks failed
HRESULT 0x80010107
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks to everyone answering in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run dbgCommand('!analyze -v') with three different dump from python REPL:

1. usermode native dump: OK
2. kernel mode dump: OK
3. managed app dump:

```
0:000> !py
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> dbgCommand('analyze -v')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
pykd.DbgException: Call IDebugControl::ExecuteWide failed
HRESULT 0x80040205
```

Then I run this script:

```py
import pykd
a = pykd.dbgCommand('!analyze -v')
print(a)
```

this script works OK with all of these dump.

I believe there is a bug. I've opened an issue:
https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd-ext/-/issues/15

Can you provide a dump which reproduce the bug to the pykd issues tracker.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the same issue, because mine runs fine in the windbg terminal. it only gets that error when I run it in a python terminal.

Also I'm debugging a live remote session, so not a dumpfile.

Comment: do you use 'remoteConnect' to start remote session ?

Comment: yeaa remoteConnect()

Comment: I will try to investigate this case. Thank you for your report

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://githomelab.ru/pykd/pykd/-/issues/78